# How do I use external libraries and plug ins like owl.carousel.js in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a simple carousel to my site. After doing a little research I found owl.carousel.js, I like the layout they use and it seems to be what I'm looking for.

Keep in mind I am new at all this. :)

My question is after I have downloaded the file and add the links to my html how do I make it work? Also I am not sure if I have to add the JS in the html or separate like I have it. On the owl site it just says call the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <a link href="main.css" rel="stylsheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div> <img src="images/images-1.jpeg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/images-2.jpeg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/images-3.jpeg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/images.jpeg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/shutterstock_204805573.jpg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/shutterstock_221107753.jpg"> </div>
      <div> <img src="images/smug%20mug%20portrait%20copy.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. Just make sure that the path to the owl script is correct. If you right click, and click Inspect Element (assuming Chrome) on the page, you should be able to go to the console. Type `owlCarous` and the rest should pop up, which would show you that the object is being loaded correctly. That should be a good first starting step.

Comment: awesome! so I did what you said on inspecting. It said *theres an error trying to load the resource* I'm guessing thats because the path is wrong which is funny cause I just copy and pasted from the site. I'll try to dabble some where and figure it out. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your html, it should work. Just add the snippet (that you mentioned first) right after you include owl carousel js file. So, the final should look like:

```
 ...
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
 });
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all just for starters, Your CSS link is set wrong, remove the hyperlink tag as link is its own tag... I think I see it, from what I see its the only option... PS You did lack a little on showing us your file locations and code...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

Comment: I totally didn't notice that hyperlink lol. Noob status. Although would it matter if I haven't styled anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Running it from the Javascript console that inspecting Chrome exposes is the best way to test IMO. Running that script is basically what you're doing when you load it via JQuery, here you're just doing it manually. If the site has a CDN, I say try it with that first, then if it's working you can download it and get it working locally.